# Sorting array based on multiple conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array with objects that looks like this:

```
[{
    id: 34,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
    }]
} ,{
    id: 35,
    users: [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 23,
    }, {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
    }]
}, {
    id: 36,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23,
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
    }]
}, {
    id: 37,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
    }]
}]
```

I want to order the array based on a couple of conditions (prioritized):
First I want the objects that have users with name 'John' AND 'Lisa' and number of users is less than 3
Secondly I want the objects that have users with name 'John' AND 'Lisa' regardless of the number of participants
Then the rest of the objects

So, the array that I put as an example, would become:

```
[{
    id: 37,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
    }]
}, {
    id: 36,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
    }]
}, {
    id: 34,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
    }]
}, {
    id: 35,
    users: [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
    }]
}]
```

I have this right now, which properly sorts based on the names AND number of participants. But if the number of participants doesn't match, then it doesn't care about the names to sort, which is wrong:

```
 const names = ['John', 'Lisa']
 unorderedLeagues.sort((a, b) => {
    const aUserIncluded = every(names, priorityName =>
      some(a.users, { name: priorityName }),
    );
    const bUserIncluded = every(names, priorityName =>
      some(b.users, { name: priorityName }),
    );

    return (
      (bUserIncluded && b.users.length <= 3) -
      (aUserIncluded && a.users.length <= 3)
    );
  });
```

How should I modify this sorting to do the type of priority I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a boolean value for checking if the wanted names are in `users`. Then take the length as well or not.

```js
var array = [{ id: 34, users: [{ name: 'John', age: 23}, { name: 'Steven', age: 24}] }, { id: 35, users: [{ name: 'John', age: 23}, { name: 'Steven', age: 24}, { name: 'Charlie', age: 24}] }, { id: 36, users: [{ name: 'Lisa', age: 23}, { name: 'John', age: 24}, { name: 'Homer', age: 24}, { name: 'Charlie', age: 24}] }, { id: 37, users: [{ name: 'Lisa', age: 23}, { name: 'John', age: 24}] }],
    find = ['John', 'Lisa'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aAll = find.every(n => a.users.find(({ name }) => name === n)),
        bAll = find.every(n => b.users.find(({ name }) => name === n));

    return (bAll && b.users.length === 2) - (aAll && a.users.length === 2) || bAll - aAll;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why do you check if length === 2? I just want to make sure that length is < 3, but there can be more than just two users.

Comment: if both name are in, the length is at least min 2.

Comment: I don't follow sorry. The length is at least min 2, yes, but not equal to two, so why do you do `===` instead of ` >2`? I need to sort based on the fact that the names are in there and number of users is < 3 OR the names are in there. SO I think changing `===2` for `<= 3` resolves my question.

Comment: Nina, what I still don't understand is how the '||' makes it be more priority if the wanted names are in users and length is X than just if the wanted names are in users?

Comment: you have two sorting criteria, one for both names **and** length and the second just for both names. the first delta check if both names are in and the length of the `users` array. the second delta uses just the check if the names are in. to 2nd q: equal two is the same as *"is less than 3"*, as in the question was mentioned. does it has changed?

Comment: Sorry, I should have wrote less or equal. My bad. I understand now. My questoin is still applies tho. Why is the first sorting criteria more priority than the second one just with an OR?

Comment: because it takes a truthy value (all numerical values without zero) first and if zero, it take the second part as result. only truty values denotes a change in the sorting. zero keeps the place (but this sorting is not stable). maybe it would help, if you take a `console` log for the returning value and the parts of if.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167259/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

This method should do the job:

```js
var unsorted = [{
    id: 34,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
      },
      {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 35,
    users: [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 23
      },
      {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
      },
      {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 36,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
      },
      {
        name: 'Homer',
        age: 24
      },
      {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
      }
    ]
  }
];

var sorted = unsorted.sort((a, b) => sortMethod(a, b));
console.log(sorted);

function sortMethod(a, b) {
  var con1a = a.users.find(u => u.name == 'Lisa') && a.users.find(u => u.name == 'John');
  var con1b = b.users.find(u => u.name == 'Lisa') && b.users.find(u => u.name == 'John');

  if (con1a && !con1b) return -1;
  if (!con1a && con1b) return 1;
  return a.users.length - b.users.length;

}
```

Side note: I had to reformat the invalid JSON first, to get it successfully parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
yourObj.sort(function(curr,next){
    return ((curr.users.filter(x=>x.name=='John'|| x.name=='Steven').length > 0) && curr.users.length < 3 )? 1 : 2;
})
```

```js
var arrObj= [{
    id: 34,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
    }]
} ,{
    id: 35,
    users: [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 23,
    }, {
        name: 'Steven',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
    }]
}, {
    id: 36,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23,
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        age: 24
    }, {
        name: 'Charlie',
        age: 24
    }]
}, {
    id: 37,
    users: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 23
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        age: 24
    }]
}];


arrObj.sort(function(curr,next){
    return ((curr.users.filter(x=>x.name=='John'|| x.name=='Steven').length > 0) && curr.users.length < 3 )? 1 : 2;
});

console.log(arrObj);
```